# How can I run a bot in loop 24 hours a day in Django?

Tags: python, django, loops

I have developed a bot which needs to be 24 hours online and I set the website up in namecheap (Just a hosting) and it kills my process when it has been running for 2 hours or something like that.

```
[UID:3232][2228262] Killing runaway process PID: 2228339 with SIGTERM
[UID:3232][2228262] Child process with pid: 2228339 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
```

This is what it returns and I would like to avoid this, I have been reading about django-background-tasks but I'm not sure if I can make it run for the whole day.

Comment: how do you run it? Some web servers run every request only 30 seconds to block DDoS attack. You should run bot as separated program and communicate with Django with Queue or MQTT - but cheap servers may not have this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for answering, could you explain to me what is Queue and MQTT

Comment: `Queue` means structure which adds items at the end and get items from the beginning. But here it means also special object which can send values between threads or processes. See multiprocessing documentation: [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes). Wikipedia: [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT). As I know Django can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) as `Queue` to run external processes and it uses `MQTT` (`RabbitMQ`) to communicate.